Is there any reason the Cassandra LWW 'timestamp' has to be a real timestamp?
When inserting data into Apache Cassandra, you can specify a custom client-side timestamp with USING TIMESTAMP <xxx>, for finer control over the last-write-wins semantics. The examples in the docs are all of using timestamps in microseconds, just generated clientside.
Is there any good reason I can't instead use a generated number that's nowhere near a realistic microsecond timestamp (eg some output of a logical clock that fits in an int64), if it would be convenient for my application to get last-write-wins semantics based off of that number?
I've tried this in cqlsh and everything seems to be working fine. (In particular, TTL expiry seems to work as normal, which was the thing that I thought might be broken by my using unrealistic timestamps). But I'm worried I might be missing something, eg if cassandra uses the timestamps as part of the compaction strategy or something (any use other than picking a winner given conflicting cells for the same primary key).

My initial thought is that using any 'custom clock' for the timestamps - which is what this is - would render a lot of additional tooling problematic at best, non-functional at worst, since they would not obey / support the custom clock.
The TTL is calculated at insertion time based on the TTL vs current time - so not surprising it is not affected.

Thanks for the reply. What sort of additional tooling do you have in mind that this could be a problem with? I can't think of any tools we're using other than cassandra itself that are reading and processing the sstables. (Other than the reaper, and compaction/repair is the thing I'm a bit worried about, but given ttl doesn't depend on the timestamp it would be at least a bit surprising if compaction/repair does)
